# Maximum call stack size exceeded error node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am writing a simple app to generate content for a blog. So, a POST request to the express server sends an object that contains html string. While I was testing the api, I got the error as `Maximum call stack size exceeded` once. The html also contains base64 encoded images. But, the size of the html content was about 1.5MB when i got the error. 
I tested again with contents having size more than 10MB, but worked fine. I don't know why it happened once.
My code to handle the post request looks something like this:

```
async function create(postData){
    if(await Post.findOne({title: postData.title})){
        throw 'Post with same title already exists!';
    }
    // find the actual user(user id is sent in req.body)
    const user = await User.findById(postData.userId);
    if(user === null || user === undefined) {
        throw 'Cannot find user with given user id while creating the post!';
    }  

    // create new post
    const newPost = postData;
    delete newPost.userId;

    const post = new Post(newPost);
    post.user = user;
    await post.save();

    // add post to user
    user.posts.push(post);
    await user.save();

    return post;
}
```

I thought `user.posts.push(post);` took more time to execute, thus blocking the call stack but every other tests succeeded with larger object size. I thought of using streams like JSONStream to handle large objects but even after testing with object sizes around 15MB worked fine.

What am i missing here?

Comment: More often than not 'maximum call stack exceeded' is a result of accidentally making a recursive call without ever triggering an exit condition

Comment: @Faissaloo yeah but I don't think I have recursive calls in my code. I am just trying to replicate the error because i don't want it to happen after i deploy it.